# How to use the command of rbreak correcly?

Tags: c++, gdb

I want to set a break at Test::Say(). The way of break Test::Say() can do it. But, the way of rbreak TestSay() can not do it and report error information following:

```
(gdb) rbreak Test::Say()
Can't find member of namespace, class, struct, or union named "main.cpp:'Test::Say()"
Hint: try 'main.cpp:'Test::Say()' or 'main.cpp:'Test::Say()'
(Note leading single quote.)
```

```
   class Test
    {
    public:
            Test()
            {
            }

            void Say()
            {
                    printf("Hello word!");
            }
    };


    int main ()
    {
            Test a;
            a.Say();
            getchar();
            return 0;
    }
```

Comment: The initial "r" in `rbreak` is for [*Regular expression*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), and that means certain characters have special meaning, like for example parentheses. Why not use the normal `break` command? Then you should be able to do just `break Test::Say` (on the other hand you should be able to do `rbreak Test::Say` as well).

Comment: My intent is to find a way that use regular expression to set a breakpoint.Yes, you are right, but if even i using the way according to format of regualr expression can not do it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend upgrading gdb to the most recent version. I have reproduced your error with gdb version 7.2:

```
 /usr/bin/gdb ./a.out   
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.2-60.el6_4.1)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /home/rbreak/a.out...done.
(gdb) rbreak Test::Say()
Can't find member of namespace, class, struct, or union named "main.cpp:'Test::Say()"
Hint: try 'main.cpp:'Test::Say()'<TAB> or 'main.cpp:'Test::Say()'<ESC-?>
(Note leading single quote.)
Breakpoint 1 (main.cpp:'Test::Say()') pending.
void Test::Say();
(gdb)
```

However with recent gdb version 7.9 rbreak works as exected:

```
$ \gdb ./a.out 
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.9.1
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./a.out...done.
(gdb) rbreak Test::Say()
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400626: file main.cpp, line 12.
void Test::Say();
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/rbreak/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, Test::Say (this=0x7fffffffdd7f) at main.cpp:12
12         printf("Hello word!");
(gdb)
```